# Android mainactivity killed, subactivities aren't

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-memory

I have an android application with multiple level of activities. 1st level is the MainActivity.java, 2nd level is a ListingActivity.java, 3rd is the DetailActivity.java. Just a normal activity structure like other android apps.

When the user navigated to the 3rd activity and leaves the app makes the app go to the background. Few days of normal usage of the phone (with the app still in background) clicking the app from the "recent apps" menu 2 things sometimes happens:

**Behaviour:**

1. Resumes the 3rd activity (DetailActivity.java), but when you click back the previous activities also gets restarted/recreated.
2. Opens the 1st activity (MainActivity.java sometimes) of the app (no activity history, like restarted the app fresh)

This happens because the OS needs memory and in order to free up memory it needs to kill unused memory. Intentionally getting the 1st behaviour or the 2nd very hard to do.

**Question/Problem:**

How or can you restart the whole app (start MainActivity.java) whenever one sub activity is killed or garbage collected? 
Is it possible to specify that the app should always do the 2nd behaviour ?

Comment: That's difficult.  I'm not sure I would try to do that.  Instead you should try to persist the state of the activity via onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: The "problem" you describe is the normal, expected behavior.

Comment: I have a vague memory that the amount of time before persistent state is discarded from background apps is a device-wide setting, since maybe 4.4 or 5.0.  My google-fu is weak tonight.

Comment: Better to post code for proper resolution to you problem.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede updated the description.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` on the `<activity>` definition for the root `Activity` (the one with CATEGORY=LAUNCHER and ACTION=MAIN) in the manifest.